# Protractor Logging and Repeats for Failed Cases

Tags: angularjs, protractor, error-logging

I have several Protractor test suites for an Angular application that I am working on that I would like to provide some logging for.

I was wondering if there was a way to log successes for tests that pass and failures, with `expected` and `actual` fields for tests that fail.

Also, I was wondering if for the tests that fail, there was a way to repeat them for a set number of times before moving on to the next test.

I found [this](http://ramt.in/how-to-run-identical-jasmine-specs-multiple-times-with-protractor/) article on executing a test multiple times but was wondering if there were a more elegant way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [protractor-flake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake) to rerun failed tests. I have a [blog post](https://qualityshepherd.com/2016/12/re-run-flakey-tests-with-protractor-flake/) on how to use it, and [example code on github](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor-example).

For logging, I use [protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter), which creates html reports, with screenshot on failures (often very helpful). Of course, there are likely others if you google around.

Comment: I've read your documentation, specifically, the Caveats section regarding custom reporting and setting the correct settings in order to have Flake re-run the failed tests and am still running into issues with getting it to re-run. Any other caveats to be aware of?

Comment: Well poo... sorry, I thought I had updated my example... and now I just have. Do a `git pull` and grab my latest code. The trick here is you need my PR that submitted to Nick's project (2.7.x or later). I use pretty, pretty `jasmine-spec-reporter` reporter, so it _definitely_ works with that ;).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I should just be able to uninstall and reinstall it through npm though right? Also, I'll let you know how my logging adventures go!